# How to prove this intersection of compact sets doesn't have the finite intersection property?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

> If $\{A_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a countable family of compact subsets of a metric space $(X, \rho)$ such that $\bigcap_{i \in \mathbb{N}} A_i = \emptyset$ then there exists a finite subset $I \subset \mathbb{N}$ such that $\bigcap_{i \in I} A_i = \emptyset$.

The definition of compactness I'm working with is that $X$ is compact if every sequence in $X$ has a convergent subsequence, with limit in $X$. I know also that a set is compact if and only if it is complete and totally bounded.

What I have tried is supposing the converse, that $\bigcap_{i \in I} A_i \neq \emptyset$ for every finite $I \subset N$ but I can't think of how to construct a sequence, which will have a convergent subsequence with limit in $\bigcap_{i \in \mathbb{N}} A_i$. I would appreciate any hints on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that whenever $F$ is a finite subset of $\Bbb N$, $\bigcap_{i\in F}A_i\ne\emptyset$. For each $n\in\Bbb N$, take $x_n\in\bigcap_{i=1}^nA_i$. This make sense, since $\bigcap_{i=1}^nA_i\ne\emptyset$. The sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a sequence of elements of $A_1$, which is a compact set. Therefore, it has a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k\in\Bbb N}$, with limit $x$. If $i\in\Bbb N$, there is some $l\in\Bbb N$ such that $n_l\geqslant i$. Therefore, $x_{n_k}\in A_i$ for each $k\geqslant l$. So, since $A_i$ is a closed set, $x\in A_i$. It follows that $x\in\bigcap_{i\in\Bbb N}A_i$, which is impossible, since this set is supposed to be empty.